# Header formatting is lost when I publish to Azure

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile, azure

My JQuery Mobile formatting doesn't work when I publish to Azure. The pjoject is an MVC C# razor site that uses JQuery mobile, Ajax, and Kendo UI. The database is on Azure and the formatting is fine until I publish the website to Azure.

The header (Jquery mobile CSS with slight modifications) goes from looking like this...

[image: header in vs]

to this...

[image: header on azure]

Has anyone dealt with this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be bundler issue. I've had similar problems with css when deploying on azure. Try disabling bundle minification and packaging by adding this line to the end of method in BundleConfig.cs. If that's the problem then you probably do not include your minified css to bundles. In production environment MVC uses style.min.css instead of style.css.

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        //some bundling code here, deleted for clarity

        BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;
    }
```